# How can I access a Posgres DATE column with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to do one API Rest with connection with Postgres SQL.

I'm just starting programing with Python, so be easy with me...hehehe

That's the code that I have:

**** Postgres Database ****

```
--drop TABLE Employee;
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    id      numeric(10) NOT NULL,
    name    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    data    date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**** No Pycharm *****

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, render_template
from datetime import date

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql://user:password@X.X.X.X:5432/correntista'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


#The connection to the database is Ok!

class Employee(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "employee"
        id = db.Column(db.NUMERIC(10), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR)
        data = db.column(db.DATE)

@app.route("/")
def index():

        emp_data = Employee.query.all()

        for emp in emp_data:
                print(emp.data)
```

**I don't know why I receiving error.

[image]

When I remove the column DATE and run works fine **

I really need your help!

Thanks :)

Comment: `db.column` isn't capitalized for date, but is (`db.Column`) for id and name. Not sure if that is what's causing the issue, though.

Comment: Thx. I suspect that I not doing the correct  DATE convert to print the column...

Comment: But I dont know how yet...

Comment: FYI, doing this `TO_DATE ('1985/12/01','YYYY/MM/DD')` is redundant. First `date`(s) are not stored formatted. Second all you have to provide is `'1985/12/01'`, it will automatically be cast to a date type.

Comment: There is more to this then what you have provided. Looks like you are using [Flask-SqlAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/). Please provide the setup code for that. Also read the information at the previous link for how to setup a model. Per @AdamKG, there seems to be some capitalization issues. Also there is no need for the `__init__`. Though if you have to use one then see the example here [Quick Start](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#quickstart).

Comment: Thx @AdrianKlaver! I updated the script with the information that you asked... I am starting in Python...

Comment: Starting in Python is one thing. Not following plain instructions is another thing. There is no evidence that you looked at the links and followed the examples there.

Comment: Sorry @AdrianKlaver, I spend many hours watching videos on youtube trying to solve this problem. At least resource I tryied to find help here.I need to build one API Rest in python and I would like to use the database Postgres. After solve this I will try to find out how to use SQLAlchemy to pass parameter INOUT to a stored procedure and get the result.

Comment: YouTube is the last place you want to go. Start with the documentation for the software you are using and follow the examples.

Comment: @AdamKG thanks for your time and your attention! Your are correct that's the problem! Thank you!         ******    data = db.column(db.DATE)     "c"olumn in lower case  *****

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)